# How to use the Bluetooth Low Energy Services?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

Want to build a chat app that can only communicate with BLE supported devices.
How to initialize the BLE service and how to pair with a device so that it can receive messages.

Comment: What did you try for far ?

Comment: I could do the normal bluetooth chat app, but I am unable to implement the LeGatt services for BLE.

Comment: BLE is not meant to write CHAT app on.

Answer (score 0):

Great idea!
The first step is to "discover" nearby devices so that you can decide to which device you want to connect. One important issue on Android is that many Android phones don't support the BLE Peripheral mode which means you can not connect and exchange with them over BLE. In this case, you would need to use another technology and this complicates things a lot.

A possible solution would be to have a look at some of the SDK's available that can do discovery for you and reduce the complexity of dealing with the BLE stack: such as google nearby, [p2pkit.io](http://p2pkit.io) or newaer.

Hope this helps...

Disclaimer: I'm one of the engineers working on [p2pkit.io](http://p2pkit.io)